# Error with custom 404 with laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, http-status-code-404, response

I have a laravel application, and I have searched for  code that makes a custom 404 error page, I found this code and I have put it in `app/start/global.php` and `app/filters.php`:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('missing', array(), 404);
});
```

But it throws a `Error in exception handler.` error. Do you have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have a view file `app/views/missing.blade.php`?

Comment: Check also if your app/storage folder is writable, because it possibly tries to write a log file.

Comment: yes I have the blade template. @TheShiftExchange

Comment: How do I made it writable? @JeroenNoten

Comment: `cd` into your `app` folder and run `chmod -R 777 storage`